# Determinant of baricenter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I want to know whether it is easy to calculate the below $\det$ or not.

$$\operatorname{det}((1-\alpha) M+\alpha \mathrm{Id}),$$
where $M=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
*_{n_{1}} & * & \cdots & * \\
0 & *_{n_{2}} & \cdots & * \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
& & & *_{n_{r}}
\end{array}\right]$ $n_{1}+n_{2}+\ldots+n_{r}=d$ and  $*_{n_{j}}$ represents an invertible $n_{j} \times n_{j}$ block and $0<\alpha <1.$

Attempt: Even though I can calculate in dim 2 and 3, I could not find a general formula for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write
$$
M = \pmatrix{M_{11} & M_{12} & \cdots & M_{1r}\\0 & M_{22} & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & M_{r-1,r}\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & M_{rr}}.
$$
Then
$$
\det((1-\alpha)M + \alpha I) = \\
\det 
\pmatrix{(1-\alpha)M_{11} + \alpha I & M_{12} & \cdots & M_{1r}\\
0 & (1-\alpha)M_{22} + \alpha I & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & M_{r-1,r}\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & (1-\alpha)M_{rr} + \alpha I} =\\
\det((1 - \alpha)M_{11} + \alpha I)\det((1 - \alpha)M_{22} + \alpha I)\cdots \det((1 - \alpha)M_{rr} + \alpha I).
$$
In other words, it suffices to separately compute the "determinant of the baricenter" for each diagonal block and multiply the results.

Notably, computing the determinant of the baricenter is equivalent to computing the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial). In particular, if $A$ is a $k \times k$ matrix, then
$$
\det((1 - \alpha)A + \alpha I) = (1 - \alpha)^k \det\left(\frac{\alpha}{1 -\alpha} I + A \right) = (1 - \alpha)^k p\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \right),
$$
where $p(t) = \det(I + tA)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $-A$. There are various ways to compute the characteristic polynomial such as the [Faddeev-LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm).